# Add external project in Android Studio project as dependency results in error not finding a file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, firebaseui

I'm currently trying to add a local clone of https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android as a dependency in my project. I don't want to import it through the standard way, because I want to make modifications to FirebaseUI. Currently I'm trying this:

**settings.gradle:**

```
include ':firebaseui'
project(':firebaseui').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../FirebaseUI')
```

my module's **build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":firebaseui")
}
```

But I get:

```
Error:(42, 0) Could not read script 'C:\Users\Gonzalo\AndroidStudioProjects\MyProject\common\constants.gradle' as it does not exist.
```

which is imported in FirebaseUI\build.gradle:

```
allprojects { project ->
    // Get constants, this is where we store things
    // like the list of submodules or the version
    project.apply from: "$rootDir/common/constants.gradle"
...
```

Is it a problem with FirebaseUI's build.gradle or mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use binary deps via `mavenLocal()` repo:

1. `git clone https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android`
2. `cd FirebaseUI-Android`
3. `gradlew tasks` // you will see `publishToMavenLocal`
4. Open `FirebaseUI-Android` into a separate instance of Intellij
5. Make your changes
6. Run `gradlew publishToMavenLocal`
7. In your own project, add `mavenLocal()` to your `repositories`
8. Then add `compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.1'` do your `dependencies`

**After all that, you are good to go.**

1. Make changes to the library
2. Publish it again via `gradlew publishToMavenLocal`
3. Re-compile your application

Comment: Either I had problems with caches or gradle was getting the external (official) version, but I had to somewhere along the way change the version to 0.4.2 to ensure that the local version was being included.

Comment: Yeah usually i change the version by appending -SNAPSHOT.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with what `$rootDir` means. If you try to build just firebase code, its parent $rootDir returns its parent folder. and the relative location of constants.gradle is valid.

Now when you add firebase as a subproject of your project, $rootDir is now your root directory and `$rootDir/common/constants.gradle` is not a valid path anymore. You may be able to get away with replacing the path with:

```
$rootDir../FirebaseUI/common/constants.gradle
```

However unless if you're making local changes to the firebase code, I would second Jared's recommendation to use binary dependencies from a maven repo.